# Save list builder values to database: Yii

Tags: php, yii

I have a list builder widget in yii which looks something like [this](http://www.eha.ee/labs/yiiplay/index.php/en/site/extension?view=listbuilder).

I want to save all the selected values in the right column to my database.How can I pass the selected values to controller? Please help in this regard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured this out for myself.

The widget already includes by default the saving code too.

[Here](https://github.com/erikuus/Yii-Playground/blob/master/protected/controllers/SiteController.php) is the link for saving list widget to database.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting an `array` after submitting the form then use `serialize()` and save. (It will convert the array to a formatted string).

```
$model->attribute=serialize($_POST['modelname']['attribute'])
-----
$model->save();
```

and use `unserialize()` while fetching the data.

Or

You can use `foreach` to traverse through the array and store each selected.

Comment: When I submit my form, it is displaying all the elements on the left hand side instead of only selected values on right side.